# addobject to array not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I try to store some Map Informations into a `NSMutableArray` but it is not working. I think there is only a minor problem that I couldn't find.

At .h File:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *annotationArray;
```

at .m File:

```
    MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithName:title subtitle:subtitle coordinate:loc];
    [annotationArray addObject:placeObject];
    NSLog(@" count: %lu", (unsigned long)[annotationArray count]); // always "0"
```

what did I wrong?

Comment: Did you initialize the array ?

Comment: Where u have allocated memory for the NSMUtable array?

Comment: Yes I forgot to allocate...

Comment: ok correct your code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you may have forgotten to initialise the array. Try to add the following line before trying to add an object to it:

```
[self setAnnotationArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see more code, but I think it's most likely your not setting up annotationArray. Are you writing `_annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` anywhere?

If not, the place for it is the class init method, or you could write in the function:

```
if (annotationArray == nil) {
_annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
}
```

You could also use `[self setAnnotationArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]]` instead of `_annotationArray`, but it depends on your synthesize statement.

I would suggest that you don't just initialize it in your function without checking if it's already been set first, because then you run the risk of overriding something else when your code gets more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this:

```
_annotationArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: What do you want? I gave an answer with the information that was provided.

Comment: There is a reason why SO has comments. although this probably is the answer this encourages many answers which in some cases might not be the right ones until the OP clearly states what he did. They could easily ask it in a comment and reply upon the OP's reply

Comment: He's mad, I don't understand too.. because I'm 90% sure that is that the problem. It's funny downvote all

Comment: Thats the problem @Fabio the 90%

Comment: @giorashc it is a bit mad to downvote all of us. However I've learned the lesson: Ask first before posting a trivial answer. 
Its not nice what you did in any case...

Comment: @giorashc it's a trivial question... please.

Comment: its not personal god forbid and since he answered than ill cancel it

Comment: @giorashc: From my obj-c exp all answers were correct. just only due to one downvote people start giving downvotes. However you were correct "get conform and answer"

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this code won't work as it is a property and you are not accessing it through the getter nor the instance variable.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I agree this might look mad :) or exaggerated but think on how this site will look if everyone will just answer based on pure assumptions.

Comment: @sEnC yeah, I missed that.

Comment: @sEnC: The instance variable probably *is* `annotationArray` (otherwise the code in the question would not compile).

Comment: @giorashc: from the symptoms it can only be a un-initialized array. so requesting further information is a waste of time.

Comment: Next time I will just comment about it. If I'd knew it would make such a fuss I would have not down voted them. I still believe people should not start answers with I think etc... Reputation points are good but some times they lead users to make fast conclusions and mediocre answers just to gain a few more points.

Comment: @giorashc, new users cant comment. how would they ask for details? In the end it is important, that answers are given. also if they do contain possibly false assumption. a down vote should be casted for wrong answers — not possibly wrong answers.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, duly noted. I did redo the down votes. I think we can move on.

Comment: @giorashc, no need to get dramatic

Answer (score 0):

at .m File: add after header

```
@synthesize annotationArray=_annotationArray;

- (void)loadView 
{
self. annotationArray =[NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Comment: explicite synthesis isnt needed anymore.